# REGEXEXTRACT of google sheet return me ERROR

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I try to use `REGEXEXTRACT` on google spreadsheet but all the time I have #ERROR

I have on my cell `1-24 sur 3 964 résultats pour "patate douce"`

And my regex is : `(\s([0-9\s]+)\s)|(^([0-9]+)\s)|(\s+([0-9]+))`

I tried my regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/h3Nkfm/3)

When I tried the simple regex `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[0-9]+")` given on [this officiel example](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=fr), I had ERROR too.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Does `A2` contain a string? If not, cast it to string like `TEXT(A2)`. Also, what are you trying to get in the end?

Comment: Besides, a `(?:^|\s)(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)(?:\s|$)` regex might be all you need.

Comment: Besides, are  you sure the data is in `A2`?

Comment: The regex works in my spreadsheet. You didn't even say what error it was: the spreadsheet gives additional information when hovering over the cell with an error.

Comment: Hi @wiktor-sreibizew, thank for your answer, I was trying your regex but doesn't work for me : http://screencloud.net/v/3o1S And yes I'm sur is in A2

Comment: @zaq my regex wotk for you? Seriously o.O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error you get on the regex you posted lets me think you are facing a locale issue. Some locales use a semicolon (;) as an argument separator instead of a comma. So, assuming the string is A1 try

```
=regexextract(A1; "\s[0-9\s]+\s")
```

Also, see this quick example

[image]

UPDATE: I changed the formula to

```
=iferror(arrayformula(if(len(A1:A); regexextract(A1:A; "r\s(.+)\sré");)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't saw my problem was (;). I'm trying your regex but I have a error : http://screencloud.net/v/w461

Comment: Yes : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Z_eBOeCTsAyoKvG2glHzDUN2_Mz_t_7Z0PXKM32sT8/edit?usp=sharing Thanks

Comment: @timothylhuillier: In D1 I entered =iferror(arrayformula(if(len(A1:A); regexextract(A1:A; "r\s(.+)\sré");))) See if that works ?